# How to set the working directory using JCL's TJclCommandLineTool?

Tags: delphi

I'm using the [JCL Delphi library](https://github.com/project-jedi/jcl) in my project. Below is my code.

```
// uses JclSysUtils;

var cmd := TJclCommandLineTool.Create(parts[0]);
if cmd.Execute(params) then
begin
    ...
end;
```

As you can see, I use `TJclCommandLineTool` to invoke an external command line program. The problem is that the external program is always running in the current directory that I started my application. I want to know how can I pass a custom working directory to the external program. JCL's document is pretty lame and I can't find related information.

Comment: Try to use ``SetCurrentDir`` before starting the external app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TJclCommandLineTool does not have options like this. So easiest way to do it:

```
//uses  System.IOUtil;
var oldDir := TDirectory.GetCurrentDirectory;
try
TDirectory.SetCurrentDirectory(ANewProgramDir);
var cmd := TJclCommandLineTool.Create(parts[0]);
if cmd.Execute(params) then
begin
//      ...
end;
finally
TDirectory.SetCurrentDirectory(oldDir);
end;
```